# Draw circle on Image using D3 - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I'm new to `D3` and facing issue in **drawing a circle on Image**. I've an Image and some shapes are there, all I have to do is draw circle on those shapes.

I'm able to draw line or circle separately using [SVG Paths and D3.js](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js) like this

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
       <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

but not getting any idea how to draw these on an Image using some coordinates. I'm trying something like this.. If I draw image first, then draw circle on it, it does not show up anywhere..

```html
<img src="https://geology.com/world/united-states-map-with-state-names.gif"
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />          
 </svg>
/>
```

And if I put Image inside SVG tag, like this;

```html
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
     <img src="https://geology.com/world/united-states-map-with-state-names.gif"
       <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />          
       />
     </svg>
```

It still does not show up.. I don't know what I'm doing wrong..

Any guesses or helping material would be appreciated.

Comment: I've added code that I'm trying right now..Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know neither  nor  should be nested inside each other.
Try something similar to this:

```html
<img src="https://geology.com/world/united-states-map-with-state-names.gif" />
<svg style='position:absolute; top: 95px; left: 400px;' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

argument style on  `style='position:absolute; top: 95px; left: 400px;' '` is only for the purpose of showing an idea of what to do, this should be done via proper css.

Comment: @NullPointer this is just an example, 'absolute' might not work for you. Please read more about css positioning here, to best fit your needs:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp